# unable to install mysqlclient on windows

Tags: python, mysql, django

An error occurred when i was installed mysqlclient.I have search for many methods to resolve it,but it did't work.I am using Windows7 64bit and python 3.4 64bit.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE0Hi.jpg)     Then i download mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl and install it with pip,another error occurred[this file is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGE0T.jpg)   I really need your help!

Comment: Please attach your errors as text, not as an image, also a list of things that you tried. Also please format your question to be readable. Otherwise, you will keep getting downvotes

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You should have [Mysql server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) installed otherwise you would be lacking some headers when trying to compile wheel

( actually, you only need connectors but for sake of easy fix)

Comment: I have read some doc,and there are three ways to connect mysql.Using mysqlclient is a bad way.I am tring to use mysql-connector-python to do it,but it seems ilke python 3.4 did't support MySQLdb module,so sad

Answer (score 0):

Even with MySQL installed, I have had install issues with 1.3.10 version on windows. I'd suggest trying 1.3.9 and seeing if that works.